# Camera follows object a little wrong (it trembles, twitches) How to do it smoothly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use LookAt(target) function:

```js
public class cub : MonoBehaviour {
    public float range = 5f, moveSpeed = 30f, turnSpeed = 150f;
    public Transform target;

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

public class cubeCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target; 
 void Update () {
        transform.LookAt(target);
        transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y + 6, target.position.z - 25);
 }
}
```

I change position of camera from got position cub, it's not right I think. for example like that, I need following object absolutely smoothly

Comment: Try using `LateUpdate` instead of `Update` in your camera script.

Answer (score 2):

```
transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y + 6, target.position.z - 25);
```

Is the source of the problem. Here you move the object a fixed amount of units each update, seemingly relying on there being 60 updates/sec. The "twitching"(also called jitter) is due to variable framerate. Games on modern hardware don't run at precisely 60fps(might be 59 in one frame, 61 in another, etc). Framerate fluctuates a lot depending on what the game and the rest of the system are doing.

It can look something like this:

- 16.667ms
- 19ms
- 25ms
- 16.667ms
- 18ms
- 19ms

After enough frames take longer than 16.667ms(~60fps), you'll notice twitching/jittering. The solution is to make changes framerate independent. The simplest way to do that is to multiply the units(6 and 25 in your case) by [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html). This changes your computations from units/frame to units/sec, independent of framerate.